# How would I go about updating qty through SQL?

Tags: magento-1.9, sql

We have a custom application being written that communicates with Magento, we're looking to update inventory at a certain frequency and are looking to do this through SQL communicating directly with the database... what is the query that would update the inventory given a where clause to a product field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant database table is named `cataloginventory_stock_item`.

This table has `product_id` which refers to `catalog_product_entity.entity_id`.

It also has `qty`.

So, if you want to update product with id `1` to have a quantity of `34`, the query that you look for might be as simple as:

```
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item SET qty = 34 WHERE product_id = 1;
```

If you do not know the product id, but you know the sku, the query might be:

```
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item SET qty = 34 WHERE product_id IN (SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE sku = 'mysku');
```

That would be the basic usage.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If I have a custom field that is unique, how would I go about finding it to gather the entity_id?

Comment: Nevermind, I figure it out... grabbing the entity_id requires SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE value = [custom_field_value]

Comment: I'm glad it works for you.